# Workaround to Bootstrap form-floating for longer label?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I am wanting to use Bootstrap's form-floating with longer labels, i.e, **text box will automatically expand on longer labels**, but it cuts off on white-space wrap when too long.
I do not want to pop it out of flow using position-relative, as this is the last resort if form-floating does not work for our needs.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tzqr36ja/3/, it happens on mobile screens, or smaller columns.

This is what I currently have based on Bootstrap's form-floating.

```css
.cms-forms-container .col-sm-6 {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px
}

.cms-form-fieldset {
  padding: 0;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.cms-form-fieldset .cms-forms-field {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 7px;
}

.cms-forms-fieldset .cms-forms-field input,
.cms-forms-fieldset .cms-forms-field textarea,
.cms-forms-fieldset .cms-forms-field select {
  max-width: none !important;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #ffffff;
  color: #666666;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.cms-forms-fieldset .cms-forms-field select {
  -webkit-appearance: menulist;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.cms-forms-field div label {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  display: inline-block !important;
}

.form-floating>.form-control {
  height: unset;
}

.form-floating>label {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="fieldset cms-form-fieldset">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cms-forms-container col-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="cms-forms-field custom-label-a">
        <div class="cms-forms-field-wrapper form-floating mb-2">
          <select class="form-control valid input validation-valid" name="custom-field-a" id="#">
            <option>n/a</option>
            <option value="Bacon">Bacon</option>
            <option value="Pork belly">Pork belly</option>
          </select>
          <label for="custom-field-a" class="cms-forms-label">
             Bacon ipsum dolor amet andouille capicola pork chop fatback filet mignon buffalo burgdoggen. 
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat dependent on how you want it to look but you can give your `<select` a height value.  Removed all the "unneeded" css just for this example.  OR a combination of width and height perhaps.

```css
.custom-select-me select {
  height: 5em !important;
}

.custom-select-me-wider select {
  height: 5em !important;
}

.custom-select-me-wider label {
  width: 22em !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="fieldset cms-form-fieldset">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cms-forms-container col-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="custom-select-me cms-forms-field custom-label-a">
        <div class=" cms-forms-field-wrapper form-floating mb-2 ">
          <select class="form-control valid input validation-valid form-select" name="custom-field-a">
            <option>n/a</option>
            <option value="Bacon">Bacon</option>
            <option value="Pork belly">Pork belly</option>
          </select>
          <label for="custom-field-a" class="custom-select-me cms-forms-label">Bacon ipsum dolor amet andouille capicola pork chop fatback filet mignon buffalo burgdoggen.</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cms-forms-container col-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="custom-select-me-wider cms-forms-field custom-label-a">
        <div class=" cms-forms-field-wrapper form-floating mb-2 ">
          <select class="form-control valid input validation-valid form-select" name="custom-field-a">
            <option>n/a</option>
            <option value="Bacon">Bacon</option>
            <option value="Pork belly">Pork belly</option>
          </select>
          <label for="custom-field-a" class="custom-select-me cms-forms-label">Bacon ipsum dolor amet andouille capicola pork chop fatback filet mignon buffalo burgdoggen.</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

WILD attempt2

```css
.custom-select-me-wider>.cms-forms-field-wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

.custom-select-me-wider select.custom-select-me {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.custom-select-me-wider label.custom-select-me {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  opacity: .65;
  transform: scale(.85) translateY(-0.5rem) translateX(0.15rem);
  border: solid 1px red;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="fieldset cms-form-fieldset">
  <div class="row mb-3 pb-3">
    <div class="cms-forms-container col-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class=" cms-forms-field custom-label-a">
        <div class="cms-forms-field-wrapper form-floating mb-2 ">
          <select class="form-control valid input validation-valid form-select" name="custom-field-a">
            <option>n/a</option>
            <option value="Bacon">Bacon</option>
            <option value="Pork belly">Pork belly</option>
          </select>
          <label for="custom-field-a" class="custom-select-me cms-forms-label">Bacon ipsum dolor amet andouille capicola pork chop fatback filet mignon buffalo burgdoggen.NOT this one!</label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cms-forms-container col-12 col-sm-6">
      <div class="custom-select-me-wider cms-forms-field custom-label-a">
        <div class="cms-forms-field-wrapper mb-2">
          <select class="custom-select-me form-control form-select valid input validation-valid " name="custom-field-a">
            <option>n/a</option>
            <option value="Bacon">Bacon</option>
            <option value="Pork belly">Pork belly</option>
          </select>
          <label for="custom-field-a" class="custom-select-me cms-forms-label">Bacon ipsum dolor amet andouille capicola pork chop fatback filet mignon buffalo burgdoggen. tester out with huge amount of text here 
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Appreciate your answer - declaring a fixed height would be the easiest solution. But we generate our field sets dynamically from questions, so some questions would be short and some are a lot longer, which is not ideal for big gaps in between. I was looking to expand the textboxes automatically perhaps.

Comment: For this I think you are going to have to get a bit more creating.  Untested but make the `cms-forms-field-wrapper` element a `display:grid;` then place the select and the label at the same single row/column and place them both on that row/column ...I might take a stab at this...

Comment: @jnnguyen  I put in a second snippet with the later one styled with the grid - probably needs some padding or margin to deal with bootstrap messing with it but try very small and large screens it should give you want to want by the grid containing the children.  Ugly borders just to show what is where